# How can I find the position of matching brace or bracket in vim script

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I know that with `%` I can jump to the matching brace and bracket, but what if I just wanna know the position of the matching brace and bracket? Are there any function to get that ? Like

```
int test(int a){return a}
```

My cursor is at the end of this line after the `}`, and so the column is 25, I wanna know its matching brace(`{`)'s position , which should be 16.

Comment: You could simply press `%%`.

Comment: @romani As what I have said, I know that `%` can move to the matching pair, but what I wanna know is the line number and column number, pressing %% do nothing for me.

Comment: 1. Press `%` to move the cursor to the corresponding brace. 2. Read the line/column in your status line. 3. Press `%` again to move back. Quick and cheap. If you really want a complicated solution, see `:help searchpairpos()`.

Comment: Actually I can do it like this, I've already written the code to do the same thing as you said, I just wanna know if there is a better choice that I can get the position without changing the position of the cursor.Anyway , thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't want to change cursor position, you'll have to use `searchpairpos()` with  `n` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Either you play with `%` and then record `cursorpos()` or `line()` + `col()`. Or you can use `searchpairpos()`, but don't forget to specify a rule to ignore bracket characters in comment context.

e.g.

```
let s:skip_comments = 'synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name") =~?'
      \ . '"string\\|comment\\|doxygen"'

function! s:SearchBracket()
  let flag = 'cnzW'
  return searchpairpos('{', '', '}', flag, s:skip_comments)
endfunction
```